# Connect to SQL Server with Management Studio using a Windows Credential while not on the domain

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, ssms

I have a client that has a SQL Server 2008 installation.  They have given me a windows domain username/password on their domain, however, my workstation is not on their domain.  I'm trying to connect with Management Studio on Vista Professional.

I've tried using the "network accounts" under "user accounts", and this works for other resources (such as exchange, TFS, and file servers) but I have had no luck with this approach for SQL Server.

Also, I'm unsure if this is a concern but this is a dev instance on their database server.  So the connection string is "Computer_Name\Instance".

A further question: how could I get Integrated Security for asp.net through cassini/Visual Studio 2008.

So far my only solution is to cave and use a SQL Server Login.  I'd like to know if I have any other options.

Comment: You can also use the Network Credential section of the control panel, but you may need to use sqlserver.domain.com:1433 as the network address. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944933

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this is [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2009/10/11/tip-how-to-run-programs-as-a-domain-user-from-a-non-domain-computer.aspx).  Very useful in the situation you mention.

Basically, you need to use the /netonly /user:domain\username switches when opening management studio, like this:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe”
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Haven't tested this with Visual Studio 2008, but it could work there as well, in answer to your other question.

Comment: awesome.. and funny that blog post is less than a month old.  I'll report back here tomorrow if this fixes VS 2008.  I'm unsure though only because the web server may run as a different process.

Answer (score 0):

The detail is a bit unclear, but if your workstation is not on their domain then are you entering the username as 'domainname\username' ?

Comment: I wish.  In Management Studio if you choose windows credential there is no place to enter a credential.  Nor do you get prompted.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/NorthwindAndPubs_2008/NorthwindAndPubs_2008_fig1.jpg  for an example of the login screen.  Notice how username/password are greyed out when windows authentication is chosen